# Where is Bjarne C++ PPP book calculator example code?

Tags: c++

The book says run `calculator01.cpp` but I could not find it anywhere.

I have already checked the website: http://stroustrup.com/Programming/

Could someone tell me where is it?

Comment: Which Chapter/page of the book ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the page you provided there](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/), there is a link to a zip file named [Complete collection of code fragments for the 1st edition (revised)](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Programming-code.zip) in which there is 6 cpp examples of a "Simple calculator":

- Chapter07\chapter.7.6.3.cpp
- Chapter07\chapter.7.7-better.cpp
- Chapter07\chapter.7.7-problematic.cpp
- Chapter07\chapter.7.8.1.cpp
- Chapter07\chapter.7.8.2.cpp
- Chapter07\chapter.7.8.3.cpp

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue--calculator01.cpp is referenced on page 208 of Programming Practices and Principles (2nd Edition), but the Supporting Code page of the website (http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/) appears to skip over calculator01.cpp .

Chrinkus on Github has a calculator01.cpp program (available at https://github.com/Chrinkus/stroustrup-ppp/blob/master/text_lib/calculator01.cpp ) that comes close to what I was expecting. There's not an "=" within the cin << statement but that can easily be added in.