# Can't find calculator01.cpp from PPP example code

Tags: c++

the books says to run `calculator01.cpp` but I can't find it anywhere.

I've tried [Where is Bjarne C++ PPP book calculator example code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624637/where-is-bjarne-c-ppp-book-calculator-example-code)
but gives me Forbidden access when accessing it.
The chapter is chapter 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download all the code from the book at Stroustrup's site as well, at:
https://stroustrup.com/Programming/code.tar

The filenames are based on the chapter names, not the names in the text; so for calculator01.cpp, which appears at the beginning of section 6.7, you'd be looking in the code/Chapter06 folder for chapter6.7.cpp - this would be identical to calculator01.cpp.

(The code.tar file above is technically for the first edition of the book, not the second; however, aside from typo corrections, chapters 6.6 and 6.7 are identical in both editions. So this particular bit of code works with either edition.)

Comment: thank you, there ins't for the new version? Of PPP version 2?

Comment: how could I list all files in https:://stroustrup.com/Programming ?

Comment: You are probably better off going through the "official" pages rather than trying to index the site folder.  https://stroustrup.com/programming.html is the main page, and https://stroustrup.com/programming_support.html is the "resources" page that includes the code tarball I posted.